# get the id of a filter in a list jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview, jquery-filter

this will create a listview with a input search for filter, i would like to know if it s possible to give an id to the input search or not (i would like to set some value in with a listener when tap on a button).

```
<ul id="listeDesMedecinsUl" data-role="listview" data-filter="true"data-filter-placeholder="enter a name"  data-inset="false" data-split-icon="gear" data-divider-theme="a">
```

Thanks sry for my english

Comment: Maybe could you give more background about why do you need that id? We could have different solutions to your problem

Comment: i have a `<select>` and when i select an want to refresh my list (`<ul><li></li></ul>`) . i have the idea to take the text from the `<select>` an to put it in the filter input, but i need the id for that ... don t know if i have been enough comprehensible i did a listener for that just for show `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#nosmedecins", function(){$("#select_list_medecins").on("change", function() {
var text = $("#select_list_medecins option:selected").text();
('#idofinput).val(text);  });});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it in this way"

```
$('[data-type="search"]').val()
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qg69F/